# Basic BJT bias circuit vs temperature

Tags: transistors

LTSPICE shows that the basic BJT bias circuit is more sensible to BETA changes over temperature rather than the saturation current changes vs temperature. I tried to edit XTI, EG and XTB parameters and what i see is that collector current changes depends almost exclusively on beta changes vs temperature, in this circuit. For example, i set XTI=0 and EG=0 so i can see the beta contribution only. I expected the collector current changes to depends mainly on saturation current changes. Am i wrong ? I have to say i don't know anything about Gummel-Poon model which is the one that ltspice uses for bjts.

[image: This is the circuit in LTSPICE]

Comment: Saturation current primarily affects Vbe vs collector current. It is strongly temperature-dependent, of course.

Comment: If it's not clear enough, I could show you using LTspice how you yourself can see that the saturation current doesn't affect beta.

Comment: You said saturation current affects Vbe vs collector current. In the circuit i simulated the Vbe reduces because the base current increases so the voltage drop across R1 increases and it makes the Vbe to reduce.  Due to the exponential relationship, small changes in Vbe cause large changes in collector current so, do Vbe reduction compensate the increase of saturation current over temperature ?

Comment: Temperature significantly impacts saturation current. However, if you are interested in seeing how saturation current affects beta (at the same temperature) then you need to set up the right experiment with LTspice. Of course, there are a wide variety of various experiments you can set up to test various questions. But you need to be very careful about how you frame each and every one of them. For example, I just did a test running the saturation current over an order of magnitude change (at same temp) and found that the beta varied about 1 part per billion in LTspice. That's not much.

Comment: So how you frame each question is critical.